# Watir: Always wait when webpage element present

Tags: cucumber, watir, watir-webdriver, pageobjects, browser-testing

A web application consistently uses this div after user actions. My test scripts have this line. verbatim, all over the place.

```
@browser.div(:id => 'loading-indicator').wait_while_present
```

Explicitly including this line everywhere is OK, but ugly and repetitive.

Using `wait_until_present` with the *next* element ("`foo`") after the loading indicator would sometimes work. However, in some cases `foo` and the loading indicator are present simultaneously, but `foo` is not `visible?` until the loading indicator disappears.

Is there a way, perhaps in `env.rb`, to indicate to watir-webdriver that it should always `wait_while` this element is present?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to check for it after every click and page load/reload you can add it to an [After Hook](https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/blob/master/lib/watir-webdriver/after_hooks.rb)

```
browser.after_hooks.add do |b| 
  b.div(id: 'loading-indicator').wait_while_present
end
```